How can I make a string of words wrap to the next line altogether in HTML/CSS?
I'm trying to make the full name of the games wrap to the next line instead of breaking the line in the middle.
I'm using Bootstrap library of code and my own CSS to make an introduction website for my portfolio.
I don't speak english fluidly, so when I try asking google for what to do, I just can't find the answer.


<p>&emsp;I am Anabelle Rosseto, a games and websites programmer! I love games such as <a class="text-danger fw-semibold text-decoration-none" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros._3" target="_blank">Super Mario Bros. 3</a>, <a class="text-violet fw-semibold text-decoration-none text-break" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Ends_with_You" target="_blank">The World Ends With You</a>, and <a class="fw-semibold text-decoration-none" href="">Donkey Kong Coutry TF</a></p>



I've tried text break, I've tried to overflow only the link part, none of it worked. I was expecting the full title of the game to wrap to the next line instead of breaking the line in the middle of it. Should I make my own Javascript for this? If there was one way to make the code treat a string of words as just one word, I'd feel greatly relieved.

are you looking for overflow-wrap?

Maybe try this? Super&nbsp;Mario&nbsp;Bros.&nbsp;3, concatenate with non-breaking-space character.
Or give the link element a fixed width. A link is an inline element though, so you'll need to change the display property.

This worked! Thank you ever so much!

The Bootstrap class for this is .text-nowrap just add it to the a tags


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>
  &emsp;I am Anabelle Rosseto, a games and websites programmer! I love games such as
  <a class="text-nowrap text-danger fw-semibold text-decoration-none" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros._3" target="_blank">Super Mario Bros. 3</a>,
  <a class="text-nowrap text-violet fw-semibold text-decoration-none text-break" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Ends_with_You" target="_blank">The World Ends With You</a>, and
  <a class="text-nowrap fw-semibold text-decoration-none" href="">Donkey Kong Coutry TF</a>
</p>



https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow

Force the parts to stay together like this:
<span style="white-space: nowrap">There will be no breaks in this part</span>

Demo:


.p1 {
  width: 220px;
}

.p2 {
  width: 340px;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
<p class="p1">
  This text can break. This text can break. <span style="white-space: nowrap">There will be no breaks in this part</span> This text can break. This text can break. This text can break.
</p>

<hr>

<p class="p2">
  This text can break. This text can break. <span style="white-space: nowrap">There will be no breaks in this part</span> This text can break. This text can break. This text can break.
</p>




You could try to use white-space nowrap; property
<p>&emsp;I am Anabelle Rosseto, a games and websites programmer! I love games such as 
  <a class="text-danger fw-semibold text-decoration-none text-nowrap" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros._3" target="_blank">Super Mario Bros. 3</a>,
  <a class="text-violet fw-semibold text-decoration-none text-nowrap" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Ends_with_You" target="_blank">The World Ends With You</a>,
  and <a class="fw-semibold text-decoration-none text-nowrap" href="">Donkey Kong Coutry TF</a>
</p>


You need to add display: inline-block css to the a tags. And since you are using bootstrap try adding inline-block class to all the a tags.
